# Как выводить скорость в методе скачивания по HTTP

Tags: java

Есть метод скачивания файла по Http:

```
private static void downloadFile(String strURL, String strPath, int buffSize) {
        try {
            /* Get connection */
            URL connection = new URL(strURL);
            HttpURLConnection urlconn;

            urlconn = (HttpURLConnection) connection.openConnection();
            urlconn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlconn.connect();

            /* Set input stream */
            InputStream in = null;

            in = urlconn.getInputStream();

            /* Set write stream */
            OutputStream writer = new FileOutputStream(strPath);
            byte buffer[] = new byte[buffSize]; // Max bytes per one reception

            /* Download */
            int i = 0;

            while ((i = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                writer.write(buffer, 0, i);
            }

            /* Cleaning */
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

Меня устраивает простой вывод вроде: `System.out.println("Speed: " + Mb + "/sec");`

Хотел использовать классы `Timer` и `TimerTask`. Но, их методы `schedule()`, `scheduleAtFixedRate()` не подходят, так как выполняются только после `Thread.sleep(x);` а я не знаю, сколько времени(`x`) займёт загрузка.

Я могу выводить количество полученных байт `i` за одну итерацию цикла(~1ms), но хочу за 1s. Можно, конечно, плюсовать в `int` переменную количество ms, в другую количество байт, и когда будет > 1000 ms выводить скорость, но наверняка есть способ по-лучше?

Comment: Можно использовать скользящую среднюю. http://findicators.com/formula-moving-average/ Удобное отображение среднего значения скорости в каждый момент времени.

Comment: я бы предложил обновлять скорость после получения данных. Для этого сохраняем время (long) начала скачивания. И создаём переменную - сколько байт приянто. Ну и в момент приёма изменить значение прнято байт и пересчиатть скорость.

Comment: @DimXenon можно, но суть в том, как её использовать

Comment: Присваиваем переменной времени значение `System.currentTimeMillis()` перед циклом. Потом в конце итерации снова вызываем метод и смотрим разницу. Равна или больше чем секунда - отправляем значение скорости в метод расчёта значения для скользящей средней.

Comment: А можно и просто в каждой итерации отправлять данные в метод расчёта СС. И точно и лишних действий делать не надо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем, за неимением лучшего, предлагаю свой костыль, воспетый и описанный в посте-вопросе:

```
private static void downloadFile(String strURL, String strPath, int buffSize) {
        try {
            /* Get connection */
            URL connection = new URL(strURL);
            HttpURLConnection urlconn;

            urlconn = (HttpURLConnection) connection.openConnection();
            urlconn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlconn.connect();

            /* Set input stream */
            InputStream in = null;

            in = urlconn.getInputStream();

            /* Set write stream */
            OutputStream writer = new FileOutputStream(strPath);
            byte buffer[] = new byte[buffSize]; // Max bytes per one reception

            /* Download */
            int i = 0;
            double getted_b = 0.0;
            long delta_t = System.nanoTime();

            while ((i = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {

                getted_b += i;

                writer.write(buffer, 0, i);

                if ((System.nanoTime() - delta_t) >= 1E9) { // If the second was held
                    int kb, mb;

                    mb = new Double(getted_b / (1024 * 1024)).intValue();
                    kb = new Double((getted_b / 1024) % 1024).intValue();

                    System.out.println(" >> Speed: " + mb + " " + kb + " Mb/sec");

                    delta_t = System.nanoTime(); // Set to zero
                    getted_b = 0.0;
                }
            }

            /* Cleaning */
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```